# Find the $\theta$ and $\phi$ values on the Bloch sphere corresponding to the state $\frac{1+i}{2}|0\rangle+\frac1{\sqrt2}|1\rangle$

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

If I have the following state:

$$
\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1\right>\right)
$$

How can I find the $\theta$ and $\phi$ values of this qubit on the Bloch sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below:
$$\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}\left(\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1\right>\right)
=
\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}} \left| 1\right>\right)
=
\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}\left(\cos(\pi/4)\left| 0 \right> + \sin(\pi/4) e^{-i\pi/4} \left| 1\right>\right)
=
C\left(\cos(\theta/2)\left| 0 \right> + \sin(\theta/2) e^{i\phi} \left| 1\right>\right)$$

Therefore
$\theta = \pi/2$ and $\phi=-\pi/4$

Comment: Just note that state $|\phi\rangle$ is not normalized as $|a|^2+|b|^2 = \sqrt{2}$. Probably the fraction before left bracket should have been $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Ok many thanks for try to solve but I make edit to brackets .please see the state again. @AlexeyKrugovets

Comment: I don't see the difference in your edition. Pls look at the Martin Vesely comment

Comment: which step do you not understand?

Comment: in step 2 the $\cos(\pi/4)=\sin(\pi/4)$ replaced the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and the $e^{-i\pi/4}$ replaced $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @BasharTaj: $C$ is a global phase of a qubit, so you can ignore it. Two quantum states which differ only in global phase cannot be distinguished.

Answer (score 5):

In last time there is a lot of questions how to find $\theta$ and $\phi$ for this particular state on Bloch sphere: $$
\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \left| 0 \right> + {\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}} \left| 1\right>
$$

I will try to demonstrate how to do so in more details in comparison with previous answer.

Generally, a quantum state can be expressed in this form:

$$
|\varphi\rangle = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle + \mathrm{e}^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle
$$
Where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are coordinates on Bloch sphere.

Regarding the particular state in question, we firstly have to get rid of complex amplitude before $|0\rangle$ to have only real number here. We can do that by multiplying whole state by so-called global phase. This multiplication does not change the state as two states which differ in global phase are identical. You can for example check probabilities of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ after multiplication. They remain same (for the state in question probability of measuring $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ in z-basis is $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$, respectively).

Mathematically, the global phase is a complex number with absolute value 1.

In our paritucar case I multiplied $|\varphi\rangle$ with $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}} = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}$ *(hence global phase is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$)*.

The result is

$$
\left| \varphi \right>={\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}} \left| 0 \right> + \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left| 1\right>
$$

Since $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}} = \mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, apparently $\phi = -\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Theta can be calculated from $\cos\frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. Hence

$$
\theta = 2\arccos\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} = 1.2310.
$$

We can verify $\theta$ with sine

$$
\theta = 2\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} = 1.2310.
$$

**Conclusion: $\theta = 1.2310$ and $\phi = -\frac{\pi}{4}$.**