# How to calculate the coefficients of a qubit from the angles of its Bloch representation?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

A quantum bit $|\psi\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ is represented on the Bloch sphere as a point on the spherical surface with $\theta = 40^°$ and $\phi = 245^°$.
Calculate the (complex) coefficients $a$ and $b$.

[Here is theory from wikipedia, that I also looked up](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313490/how-are-linear-combinations-of-qubit-states-represented-in-the-bloch-sphere)

It would be nice to have a step-by-step guide based on a concrete example for reverse operation like it was made here: [How can I find the $\theta$ and $\phi$ values of a qubit on the Bloch sphere?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9404/how-can-i-find-the-theta-and-phi-values-of-a-qubit-on-the-bloch-sphere)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the first link:

$$ |ψ⟩=\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)|0⟩+e^{iϕ} \sin\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)|1⟩ $$

Identify common coefficients:
$$ a =        \cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) $$
$$ b = e^{iϕ} \sin\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) $$

Then simply plug in your angles $θ$ and $ϕ$. Be sure your calculator knows whether you are inputting your angles as radians or degrees (eg. $40°=\frac{2π}{9}$ rad)!